# JAVAMAIL + ERROR + Connection closed by remote host

Tags: jakarta-mail

I'm trying to send mass emails, Achievement send 20 emails on average and then I get this error:

javax.mail.MessagingException: Can't send command to SMTP host; nested exception is: java.net.SocketException: Connection closed by remote host

CODE JAVA:

```
public void mandarEmail(String correos, String mensaje, String asunto) {
    final String username = "docs-gf@usmp.pe";
    final String password = "Docpass";
    Message message;

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "pod51004.outlook.com");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
        }
    });
    try {
        message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("Hello my friend"));
        message.setSubject("I love u very much");
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("ivan@hotmail.com"));
        message.setContent(mensaje, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
        Transport.send(message);
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {
        props = null;
        message = null;
    }
}
```

I'm forgetting something?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the server doesn't want you to send mass emails and so is rate limiting you.  Turn on [JavaMail Session debugging](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) and there might be more information from the server in the protocol trace.

Comment: i add the lines:

"props.put("mail.smtp.debug", "true");" and "session.setDebug(true);"

and the messahe is the same

Comment: It is "props.put("mail.debug", "true");"

Comment: Four years later and you're back to working on this problem?  Guess it wasn't that important.  :-)  Find the JavaMail debug output and post it.